# Intent for screen orientation change

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation

I'm wondering whether android broadcasts a intent when the screen orientation changes. I am programming a live wallpaper and want to deal with it when the screen orientation changes. I can handle the same with regular apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android system doesn't broadcast an Intent, but restarts the activity by default. 
If you want to override this you should override `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method of your activity. To get this method called you should also specify the changing in `android:configChanges` attribute in your manifest file.

See what and how to specify [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges).

Comment: But I'm dealing with a live wallpaper here. Not an Activity. Thanks for your answer @Vladimir

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. Thanks for the answer @Vladimir Ivanov

Answer (score 2):

I think "android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED" is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it does, but you can always check the configuration at a repeating interval to see if it changed.  To get the configuration call `getResources().getConfiguration()` and inspect the orientation.

Comment: @Vladimir Ivanov answer is better.  I didn't realize that WallpaperService is a subclass of Context and, therefore, it implements onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Well if the app is not in the foreground, this

> "onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)"

method does not work (for example when the app displays an overlay in a service)