# How the layout design is kept same on the rotation in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a layout which particularly having some buttons situated at its bottom. It works fine for portrait view. But when I rotate my tab the layout gets disturbed. Could anyone tell me how to keep the same view of layout on both rotations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5563350/1777090, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can create Layouts for both portrait and landscape mode Create
  Lauout-land folder and put your layout with same name this is how you
  can manage your layout orientation

Comment: what if I do some changes on a layout in portrait mode and rotate the screen? Would those changes remain in landscape mode?

Comment: You Can create two layouts one in portrait mode and one in landscape mode with same name in portrait layout you can put xml layout as portrait mode and in landscape layout as per landscape mode when you change orientation from portrait to landscape the landscape layout from layout-land folder will be shown in screen

Comment: if i do changes to the image loaded on the touch surface in portrait mode, will not remain when I switch to the landscape mode.

Comment: make id name of image same in both portrait and landscape mode

Comment: put android:configChanges="keyboardhidden|orientation" in your activity in mainfest this blocks the activity to refresh when switching from portrait to landscape